# QPropertyAnimation not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use Qt's animation framework. I'm using some sample code from Qt's website, but it's not working, error: `setGeometryDp: Unable to set geometry 100x30+0+0 on QWidgetWindow/'QPushButtonClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  120x30+0+0 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).`

```
QPushButton button("Animated Button");
button.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30);
button.show();

QPropertyAnimation animation(&button, "geometry");
animation.setDuration(10000);
animation.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation.setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

animation.start();
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects go out of scope

This works:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();
button->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30);
button->show();

QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

animation->start();
```

Edit:
My final solution

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30);
button->show();

QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));

connect(animation, SIGNAL(finished()), animation, SLOT(deleteLater()));

animation->start();
```

Comment: *This works*, **and it is a perfect example of memory leaking**. Please, set a parent for the `button` you are instantiating since you are allocating on the heap. see [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice buddy, I totally missed that.

Comment: Also, connect the animation's ```finished()``` signal to its ```deleteLater()``` slot to prevent more leakage.